# StreamReader.Read(Span<char>) vs StreamReader.Read(char[], int, int) performance

Tags: c#, html, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to read text files in a very optimized way. Right now, I'm looking at `StreamReader.Read(Span<char>)` and `StreamReader.Read(char[], int, int)`.

I know `Span<>`s were designed to be faster by not allocating data on the heap. But I don't understand the benefit offered by using a `Span<>` here.

Don't both versions require the read character to be copied one by one to my buffer? So does `Span<>` offer any advantage here?

Comment: If your source is a contiguous section of memory that is _NOT_ an array (such as a string), you should use `Span<char>`, which is vastly more efficient than creating a char array from the string.

Comment: @DavidL: I guess this is why it was confusing. An array is the only data structure that would seem to make sense to me. So I'm writing the data to a `char[]`.